# Como aplicar background-color ao elemento HTML p?

Tags: html, css, background-color

Preciso aplicar a propriedade CSS `background-color` ao elemento HTML `p` mas o que está acontecendo é que esse `background-color` pega toda a largura de uma `div` por exemplo se for o elemento pai e não só colore o elemento `p`.

O que eu tenho:

[image: imagem atual]

O que eu preciso:

[image: imagem necessária]

Comment: Não temos o conhecimento do código, mas me parece que a tag mais correta seria `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc., já que se trata de um título - aparentemente. `<p>` serve para envolver parágrafos propriamente ditos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque o texto específico dentro da *tag* `span` e deixe o seu CSS da seguinte forma:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      p span{
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><p><span>PARAGRAFO</span></p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Fiz o teste aqui e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Dei +1 porque efetivamente esta solução resolve o problema mas deixo a ressalva de que adicionar _markup_ para lidar com questões visuais é incorreto. O CSS existe para isso mesmo.

Answer (score 7):

## Solução via CSS

A solução depende do restante da tua *markup*, mas se tens um `<p/>` dentro de uma `<div/>`, sem adicionar mais *markup* podes atribuir a propriedade [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) ao teu paragrafo:

```css
p{
    background-color:orange;
    display:inline-block;    /* deixa de ser bloco e passa a bloco de linha */
}
```

Desta forma a *markup* mantém-se igual e fazes uso das propriedades de CSS para ajustar a apresentação do elemento.

#### Em detalhe

Por defeito o elemento `<p/>` é apresentado como um bloco, o que faz com que o mesmo ocupe toda a largura da tela.

Ao aplicar no CSS a propriedade `display` com o valor `inline-block` estamos a indicar que pretendemos que o `<p/>` seja apresentado como um bloco de linha, cuja característica do mesmo é que a sua largura não é superior à largura do seu conteúdo salvo se especificado.

#### Exemplo

```css
p{
    background-color:orange;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>CONSULTÓRIO</p>
</div>
```

Comment: quando você diz que o elemento é block por "defeito", tu quis dizer "default" ou que esse comportamento é defeituoso?? ;)

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo Em pt_PT, quando dizemos "[por defeito](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1074.aspx)" tem o mesmo significado de "default" em inglês. De igual forma, em pt_PT "por defeito" é diferente de "um defeito" ou "defeituoso". A palavra "defeito" isolada ou noutro contexto já pode ter o sentido a que te referes, mas neste caso não por estar precedida de "por" que trás um novo significado à mesma. :)

Comment: Ah entendi, é que não conhecemos essa expressão no pt_BR. Obrigado pela explicação. :)

Answer (score 5):

Seu CSS está funcionando perfeitamente bem, só faltou entender como funciona o `<p>`. Por padrão, a largura de um parágrafo é 100%, mesmo que o texto contido neste não pegue toda a largura.

Para obter o efeito desejado, basta mudar esta característica com um `float:left`, ou mesmo um `display:inline-block`. Segue exemplo funcional:

```css
.reduzido { float:left; background-color: #fc9 }

.texto { clear:both }
```

```html
<p class="reduzido">CONSULTÓRIO</p>

<p class="texto">Texto texto texto texto texto texto texto.</p>
```

Desta forma você não tem que desestruturar seu HTML original para obter o efeito desejado, e o elemento continua com as características de bloco. Note que é conveniente usar `clear:both` ou ao menos `clear:left` no elemento seguinte, para garantir que ele comece na linha de baixo. Com o espaço para outras coisas depois do parágrafo, outros elementos podem ficar na mesma linha sem o `clear`.